# Are Dark Soul's Steam servers VAC secured?

Tags: steam, dark-souls

Now that Steam has liberated us from the icy clutches of GFWL, does anybody know if the new servers are VAC secured or not? Being able to try out different builds and theorycrafting was a pretty big part of my endgame, but I don't want to risk a VAC ban for something trivial.

So has anybody found any information pertaining to the VAC status of the new servers?

Comment: You could just play offline mode until you are ready to go online with a legit build.

Comment: Well I usually make these builds with the intent of trying them in pvp (no infinite whatever hacks though because that's just lame).

Comment: At the moment, no - Not that I've heard of anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you're basically using a save editor of some sorts. I don't see how that would even be detected by any cheat detector (assuming you use realistic stat values)

Comment: I usually use cheat engine to change memory addresses and hack items/souls into the game. I always keep my items and levels legit, just not the means I acquire them :P

Comment: You can probably do that in offline mode and then switch to online after you got your souls and items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not VAC secured.

For proof look at the store page. Games that are VAC secured have 'Valve anti-cheat enabled' listed on the right hand side.

Need more proof? Browse the complete list of games that have VAC enable. http://store.steampowered.com/search/?category2=8. Dark Souls is not there.